# Trigger or event to get average from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average

```
ratings_table
-------------------------
id(PK)  color(FK)  rating
=========================
1       green      5  
2       green      2
3       blue       4
4       yellow     4
5       blue       3

colors_table:
---------------------
color(PK)  avg_rating
=====================
green      ?  
blue       ?
yellow     ?
```

How can I set the average rating of each color? I would like to change it automatically when a new data inserted into the rating_table or a record updated.

I guess it quite easy, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `AVG()`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit the question to add any Trigger code attempted by you so far. So we can guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to have `colors_table` as a view instead of a table where you need to mess around with triggers:

```
CREATE VIEW colors AS
SELECT   color, AVG(rating)
FROM     ratings_table
GROUP BY color
```

Comment: So I don't really need to store average ratings. It is logical, to be honest... Thank you very much!

Comment: @TheFurgeurge I wouldn't bother storing it, unless you have gazillions of records and querying the view just becomes too slow.

Comment: Is there any easy way to store it?